# Explanation for OEIS $\text{A}000157$ – "Number of Boolean functions of $n$ variables"

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, boolean-algebra, oeis

I'm having trouble understanding [OEIS $\text{A}000157$](https://oeis.org/A000157), not necessarily its description, but rather its terms. I've already visited [how many semantically different boolean functions are there for n boolean variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505393), but the results didn't seem to match those listed in this sequence. The definition and elements are as follows:

> Number of Boolean functions of n variables.
>
> ```
> 1, 2, 7, 111, 308063, 100126976263592, 131867858014413288241233435594064, ...
> ```

This is unclear to me for the following reason: What are the logical operators one should use? By looking at the first and seconds terms of this sequence, I assumed that $\lor\text{ and }\land$ are the only allowed operators, of course including brackets as needed. But this reasoning doesn't *seem* to hold for the third term:

Let $\space f:\Bbb{B}^3\rightarrow\Bbb{B}$. It can therefore have the following forms:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}f(a,\:b,\:c)=a\land b\land c\\ f(a,\:b,\:c)=a \lor b\lor c\\f(a,\:b,\:c)=(a\land b)\lor c\\
f(a,\:b,\:c)=a\lor(b\land c)\\f(a,\:b,\:c)=(a\land c)\lor b\\f(a,\:b,\:c)=(a\lor b)\land c\\f(a,\:b,\:c)=(a\lor c)\land b\\f(a,\:b,\:c)=(b\lor c)\land a\\\cdots\end{array}\right.$$

Is my understanding  flawed, or are any of the statements above, in fact, semantically equivalent? Are the boolean operations used really $\lor$ and $\land$ (I feel like excluding $\lnot$ is quite odd)? Moreover, is there a formula for this sequence?

Comment: Did you look at [OEIS A000370](http://oeis.org/A000370) which is linked to from A000157?

Comment: @Somos I did, and to be completely honest, I am not sure I understand that one either.

Comment: You can read the paper by Harrison mentioned on the OEIS page here https://oeis.org/A000370/a000370.pdf, it contains the definition.

Comment: While A000370 as explained in the answer is a natural sequence to come up with (for a combinatorialist), and A000157 is just that divided by two, I wonder why anyone would consider that latter sequence. It doesn't seem to count any naturally occuring structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  reader  may  be  interested  to know  that  there  is  a  certain
equivalence of boolean  functions that may be counted by **Power Group
Enumeration.** This is the case where equivalence includes permutation
of the inputs and / or  simultaneous complementation of the inputs and
possible  complementation  of  the  outputs.  We  do  not  repeat  the
details of  the algorithm here as  it is exactly the  same as what
was         documented        at         this        [MSE         link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/) or  at this [MSE
link    II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180525/).    The
algorithm  can be  described  very straightforwardly  as counting  the
number of  ways we  may cover  the cycles  of permutation  $\alpha$ by
cycles of a  permutation $\beta$ where $\alpha$ is  a permutation from
the group permuting the slots and $\beta$ from the group permuting the
repertoire.   Hence we  have it  solved if  we can  compute the  cycle
indices of the two groups.

In the  present case  the group  acting on the  values going  into the
slots i.e. the repertoire is trivial and has cycle index by inspection

$$Z(P) = \frac{1}{2} a_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} a_2.$$

The challenge is  the cycle index $Z(Q)$ of the  symmetric group and /
or complementation acting on the  $2^N$ input vectors / binary strings
by permuting  bits and /  or complementing  them. We have  included an
algorithm by enumeration (compute the  action on the $2^N$ strings and
factor it into cycles), but this  will only serve as a verification of
the correctness of the algorithm  from first principles because of the
exponential  growth of  the number  of  terms being  permuted. We  now
explain the computation  from first principles. There  are two classes
of permutations here, the first  resulting from permuting the bits and
the  second   from  permuting  bits  followed   by  complementation  /
inversion. Start with the first.   A permutation $\tau\in S_N$ acts on
each  of the  $2^N$ strings  by  rotating bits  according its  cycles,
i.e. the bits on every cycle are shifted by one position (except for a
fixed point). With a cycle from  $\tau$ of length $n$ we can therefore
obtain cycles  belonging to $\beta$  of length $d|n$ for  all divisors
$d$ of $n$, depending  on the period $d$ of the  substring of the bits
corresponding to  the cycle.  Such  a string  of period length  $d$ is
obtained by repeating an aperiodic  binary string of length $d$, $n/d$
times.  It  follows that  the contribution for  $\tau$ is  obtained by
iterating over all combinations of divisors of the cycles from $\tau,$
recording the value  $d$ of the length of the  resultant cycle and the
number of possible assignments, which  is $\gamma_1(d),$ the number of
aperiodic binary strings of length $d.$ Given such a tuple of divisors
the length of the combined cycle in $\beta$ is the LCM of the divisors
and the  total number of  such cycles is  given by dividing  the total
number  of  terms   (product  of  the  $\gamma_1(d)$)   by  the  cycle
length. Observe  that for the terms  membership in the set  of strings
from  $2^N$ for  a  given tuple  of divisors  is  disjoint and  $\tau$
preserves  this   property.   This   is  sufficient  to   compute  the
contribution to $\beta$ from the vector of divisors and the product of
all contributions  then yields  the factored $\beta$  corresponding to
$\tau.$ We just need $\gamma_1(d)$ but we have

$$\sum_{d|n} \gamma_1(d) = 2^n \quad\text{and hence}\quad
\gamma_1(n) = \sum_{d|n} 2^d \mu(n/d).$$

Continuing  with the  second class  of  permutations we  use the  same
scheme of classifying according to periodicity on the cycles of $\tau$
by constructing vectors  of divisors for the cycle  lengths of $\tau.$
The object remains  to determine the lengths of the  cycles that these
bit strings are on.  We observe that the circular orbits of substrings
of the $2^N$ bit strings lying on a cycle generated by $\tau$ now have
the property  that not only is  the string rotated by  one position to
get to  the next, but  also that the entries  that are at  odd offsets
from the start of the orbit are  not only rotated, but also have their
bits inverted. This means  that for a divisor $d$ that  is odd we take
$2d$ steps  to return to the  start, since the source  string will not
appear among the  inverses (we would need an even  number of bits) and
the non-inverses advance by two  positions with every appearance.  The
situation is somewhat more complicated  when $d$ even. Supposing first
that the source string will not appear among the inverses we then have
that  the  orbit still  has  length  $d.$  The odd-offset  values  are
inverted but with  $d$ even the source  is reached at the  end after a
total  of $d$  operations, with  the inverted  values at  odd offsets.
This  leaves  the case  where  the  source  string appears  among  the
inverses. For  this to  happen it  must consist of  an even  number of
repetitions of a  bit string followed by its inverse.  For a string of
length $n$ these are given by

$$\sum_{d|n} [[d\;\text{even}]] \times[[n/d\;\text{odd}]]\times
\gamma_1(n/d).$$

Here the segments of length $n/d$ alternate between not being inverted
and being inverted.  The length  must be odd because inversion applies
at  odd offsets  in the  orbit. With  $n=2^p m$  and $p$  maximal this
becomes

$$\sum_{d|m} \gamma_1(n/d/2^p) = 
\sum_{d|m} \gamma_1(m/d) = \sum_{d|m} \gamma_1(d) 
= 2^m \times [[n\;\text{even}]].$$

The Iverson bracket  appears here because we get zero  when $n$ is odd
and  not $2^n$,  because  there are  no even  divisors  and the  first
Iverson bracket in the first formula fails on all $d.$

Introducing $v_2(n) = p$ we then  have for the number $\gamma_2(d)$ of
aperiodic strings where  the source string appears  among the inverses
by Mobius inversion

$$\gamma_2(n) = 
\sum_{d|n} [[d\;\text{even}]] \times 2^{d/2^{v_2(d)}} \mu(n/d).$$

It remains to determine the length  of the cycle these strings are on,
which must be $d/2$ for one segment followed by its inverse since with
four segments etc. the string would  not be aperiodic. We now have all
the ingredients to apply the construction from the first class without
complementation,  except  that  technically   we  have  two  kinds  of
contributions for $d$ where $\gamma_2(d)$ is not zero and $d$ is even,
corresponding to source strings appearing  and not appearing among the
inverses. The computation  remains the same -- compute the  LCM of the
length of  all cycles  for $\beta$  being generated  by the  cycles of
$\tau$  and the  number of  strings having  this profile  in terms  of
divisors and inversion to determine the number of cycles of the length
that was obtained.  The contribution to the number of strings from the
two cases  is a  factor of $\gamma_2(d)$  or $\gamma_1(d)-\gamma_2(d)$
accordingly.  This concludes the documentation of the algorithm.

We may now compute the cycle indices of the slot permutation group for
use with PGE. For example $n=5$ will produce

$${\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{32}}{240}}+1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{16}{a_{{2}}}^{8}
+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{2}}}^{12}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{3}}}^{8}
\\ +{\frac {13\,{a_{{2}}}^{16}}{120}}
+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{4}{a_{{6}}}^{2}
+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{6}
\\ +1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{4}{a_{{4}}}^{6}+1/10\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{5}}}^{6}
+1/6\,{a_{{2}}}^{4}{a_{{6}}}^{4}+1/10\,a_{{2}}{a_{{10}}}^{3}.$$

We  can  also  compute  cycle  indices  that  are  not  accessible  by
enumeration, e.g.  for $n=16$  the cycle  index starts  ($16!\times 2$
permutations)

$${\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{65536}}{41845579776000}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{32768}{a_{{2}}}^{16384}}{348713164800}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{16384}{a_{{2}}}^{24576}}{7664025600}}
\\ +{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8192}{a_{{2}}}^{28672}}{348364800}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{4096}{a_{{2}}}^{30720}}{30965760}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{2048}{a_{{2}}}^{31744}}{5529600}}+\cdots$$

The  sequence of  the count  of these  equivalence classes  of boolean
functions is

$$2, 5, 26, 1072, 9340584, 6406603624626816,
\\ 16879085743296494006611933604867584,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A299104](https://oeis.org/A299104). The Maple code
for this computation goes as follows.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

APBS := n -> add(2^d*mobius(n/d), d in divisors(n));

MXODD_DIV :=
proc(n)
local m;

    m := n;

    while type(m, `even`) do
        m := m/2;
    od;

    m;
end;

APBS_INV := n ->
add(`if`(type(d, `even`), 2^MXODD_DIV(d), 0)*mobius(n/d),
    d in divisors(n));

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;

pet_cycleind_bin_p :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, prod, term, flat, iter;

    if n=1 then return a[1]^2 fi;

    iter :=
    proc(pos, cycs, sofar)
    local d, len, comb;

        if pos > nops(cycs) then
            len := lcm(seq(q, q in sofar));
            comb := mul(APBS(q), q in sofar);

            prod := prod*a[len]^(comb/len);
            return;
        fi;

        for d in divisors(op(1, cycs[pos])) do
            iter(pos+1, cycs, [op(sofar), d]);
        od;
    end;

    res := 0;

    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

        prod := 1;
        iter(1, flat[2], []);
        res := res + flat[1]*prod;
    od;

    res;
end;

bin_p_bool :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx, vars;

    idx := pet_cycleind_bin_p(n);
    vars := indets(idx);

    subs([seq(v=2, v in vars)], idx);
end;


pet_cycleind_bin_snp :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, prod, term, flat, iter;

    if n=1 then return 1/2*a[1]^2+1/2*a[2] fi;

    iter :=
    proc(pos, cycs, sofar)
    local d, q, len, comb;

        if pos > nops(cycs) then
            len := 1;
            comb := 1;

            for q to nops(cycs) do
                d := op(1, sofar[q]);
                if op(2, sofar[q]) then
                    len :=
                    lcm(len, d/2);
                    comb :=
                    comb *
                    APBS_INV(d);
                else
                    if type(d, `odd`) then
                        len :=
                        lcm(len, 2*d);
                    else
                        len :=
                        lcm(len, d);
                    fi;

                    comb :=
                    comb *
                    (APBS(d)-APBS_INV(d));
                fi;
            od;

            prod := prod*a[len]^(comb/len);
            return;
        fi;

        for d in divisors(op(1, cycs[pos])) do
            if APBS_INV(d) > 0 then
                iter(pos+1, cycs, [op(sofar), [d, true]]);
            fi;
            iter(pos+1, cycs, [op(sofar), [d, false]]);
        od;
    end;

    res := 0;

    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

        prod := 1;
        iter(1, flat[2], []);
        res := res + flat[1]*prod;
    od;

    res/2 + pet_cycleind_bin_p(n)/2;
end;

bin_snp_bool :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx, vars;

    idx := pet_cycleind_bin_snp(n);
    vars := indets(idx);

    subs([seq(v=2, v in vars)], idx);
end;

bin_snpn_bool :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_cols, res, a, b,
    flat_a, flat_b, cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    idx_slots := pet_cycleind_bin_snp(n);
    idx_cols := 1/2*a[1]^2+1/2*a[2];

    res := 0;

    for a in idx_slots do
        flat_a := pet_flatten_term(a);
        for b in idx_cols do
            flat_b := pet_flatten_term(b);

            p := 1;
            for cyc_a in flat_a[2] do
                len_a := op(1, cyc_a);
                q := 0;

                for cyc_b in flat_b[2] do
                    len_b := op(1, cyc_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q;
            od;

            res := res + p*flat_a[1]*flat_b[1];
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;


pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;

ENUM_cycleind_bin_p :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local cind, perm, src, autom, ind, d;

    src := [];

    for ind from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, `base`, 2);
        src := [op(src), d[1..n]];
    od;

    cind := 0;

    perm := firstperm(n);

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        autom :=
        [seq([seq(src[q][perm[p]], p=1..n)],
             q=1..2^n)];

        cind := cind +
        pet_autom2cycles(src, autom);

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    cind/n!;
end;

ENUM_cycleind_bin_snp :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local cind, perm, src, autom, ind, d;

    src := [];

    for ind from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, `base`, 2);
        src := [op(src), d[1..n]];
    od;

    cind := 0;

    perm := firstperm(n);

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        autom :=
        [seq([seq(1-src[q][perm[p]], p=1..n)],
             q=1..2^n)];

        cind := cind +
        pet_autom2cycles(src, autom);

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    cind/n!/2 + ENUM_cycleind_bin_p(n)/2;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The sequence A000370 enumerates Boolean functions up to an equivalence relation. More precisely, a function with any of its inputs or output negated is equivalent to the original function. Also, if the inputs are permuted, it is equivalent as well. So the sequence enumerates the equivalence classes. In the case of $n=2$, for example, there are $4$ equivalence classes. $f(A,B)=T$ is one class with $2$ members, $f(A,B)=A$ is another with $4$ members, $f(A,B)=A\lor B$ with $8$ members, and $f(A,B)=A\oplus B$ with $2$ members. Given this, then $A000157(n) = A000370(n)/2$ as stated in the OEIS entry for A000157.