# Understanding the relation between central extensions and 2-cocycles and coboundaries

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

### Context

This is basically the lecture note I received on central extensions (we were *not* introduced to group cohomology before this):

> If
>
> $$1 \to A \to G \to B \to 1$$
>
> is a non-trivial central extension (meaning, not a direct product),
>   then it is the opposite type of extension from a semidirect product.
>
> If A is central, then it is of course abelian, and it is easier to
>   discuss it in additive notation.   To keep additive and multiplicative
>   groups separate, let's say that A is additive and that exp(A) is a
>   purely formal exponentiation of A in which the group law is changed to
>   multiplication,  For instance, you can say that $C_n = \exp(\Bbb
>  Z/n)$.   Our exact sequence becomes
>
> $$1 \to \exp(A) \to G \to B \to 1  (*)$$
>
> As in the case of semidirect products, central extensions have a
>   synthetic version and a descriptive version.  I'll start with a
>   descriptive version.
>
> As in the case of a semidirect product, we can analyze this by
>   choosing a section of exp(A) in $G$, i.e., a set which has one
>   representative of each coset.  Since now the whole concern is that
>   possibly no section is a group complement, we can let $S$ be any
>   section of $\exp(A)$ in $G$ whatsoever. $S$ is still canonically
>   bijective with $B$, and I want a name for the bijection from $B$ to
>   $S$, so I guess I will write $s = \gamma(b)$.
>
> Every element of $G$ is uniquely described as $\gamma(b) \exp(a)$ for
>   some $b$ in $B$ and some $a$ in $A$.  Since $A$ is central, you can
>   check that the enitre group law of $G$ is determined by what happens
>   when you multiply two elements of $B$ as elements of $G$.  Namely you
>   get
>
> $$\gamma(b_1) \gamma(b_2) = \gamma(b_1 b_2) \exp(c(b_1,b_2))$$
>
> where $c$ is some function from $B \times B$ to $A$.   You can think
>   of $c$ as the "correction" to the group law in $G$ as compared to the
>   group law in $B$.  (By the way it is a lot like a phase correction in
>   quantum mechanics, and this is not even a coincidence, central
>   extensions of groups are fundamental in QM.)
>
> Anyway, you can check that the associative law in G implies the
>   identity
>
> $$c(b_2,b_3) - c(b_1 b_2,b_3) + c(b_1,b_2 b_3) - c(b_1,b_2) = 0$$
>
> A function $c:B \times B \to A$ in general is called a 2-cochain, while one
>   that satisfies this identity is called a 2-cocycle. Note that set of
>   2-cochains is a group $C^2(B;A)$ under addition, and the subset of
>   2-cocycles is a subgroup $Z^2(B;A)$ of the 2-cochains.  (In other
>   words, the cocycle constraint happens to be additive.)
>
> The 2-cocycle c is not uniquely determined by the central extension
>   (*), because you can expect a different cocycle $c'$ if you change the
>   section $S$ to some other section $S'$. In this case you can check that
>   $c$ and $c'$ differ as follows for some function $d$ from $B$ to $A$:
>
> $$c'(b_1,b_2) - c(b_1,b_2) = d(b_2) - d(b_1 b_2) + d(b_1)$$
>
> The right side (where here d can be arbitrary) is called a
>   2-coboundary, and they make a subgroup $B^2(B;A)$ of $Z^2(B;A)$.   **So,
>   the central extension (*) determines an element of the quotient group**
>
> $$H^2(B;A) = Z^2(B;A)/B^2(B;A)$$
>
> This specially constructed abelian group is called the 2nd cohomology
>   of $B$ with coefficients in $A$.  It is part of a larger list of
>   abelian groups called the cohomology of $B$, and (although I will skip
>   this digression entirely) it is all a special case of cohomology as it
>   arises in topology.
>
> As with semidirect products, you can also reverse the construction to
>   synthesize an associative group law on $G$, if you are given an
>   abelian group $A$, another group $B$, and a 2-cocycle $c:B \times B
>  \to A$.   Moreover, if two cocycles differ by a coboundary, then they
>   will make the same $G$.
>
> In this sense, the set of central extensions of $B$ by $A$
>   miraculously organizes into another abelian group $H^2(B;A)$.  The
>   definition of $H^2(B;A)$ looks very cumbersome at first when $B$ has
>   any appreciable size.  However, there are various equivalent
>   definitions for it and various methods to calculate it, and explicit
>   answers are known in a wide range of cases.
>
> **So, exercise: Compute $H^2(C_2;\Bbb Z/2)$ directly from the definition
>   to determine the ways to centrally extend $C_2$ by $C_2$.   I'll give
>   away the answer that there are two of them.**

### Questions

1. Although I understand the mathematical definition of $Z^2(B;A)/B^2(B;A)$ from here, it's not clear from here how $Z^2(B;A)/B^2(B;A)$ is *equivalent* to the central extensions of $B$ by $A$. Could someone please clarify a bit? What does the sentence: "**So, the central extension (*) determines an element of the quotient group $H^2(B;A) = Z^2(B;A)/B^2(B;A)$**" even mean? How does the central extension $1 \to A \to G \to B \to 1$ *determine* an element of the given quotient group?
2. I more or less understand what $Z^{2}(B;A)/B^{2}(B;A)$ mathematically means. $Z^2(B;A)$ is the group of functions $c: B \times B \to A$ that satisfies the identity $c(b_2,b_3) - c(b_1 b_2,b_3) + c(b_1,b_2 b_3) - c(b_1,b_2) = 0$ while I think $B^2(B;A)$ is a subgroup that sets up an equivalence relation, namely that $c'$ and $c$ are equivalent if $c'-c$ lies in $B^2(B;A)$. Now the point is I do not know any cohomology as such and I'm not sure how exactly to calculate $Z^2(C_2, \Bbb Z_2)/B^2(C_2, \Bbb Z_2)$ only from first principles (and using the quoted material). Could someone tell me how to proceed with this exercise? Even some hints might be helpful.

Comment: The exercise tells you to compute it directly from the definition, which means calculate $Z^2(C_2,{\mathbb Z}_2)$ and $B^2(C_2,{\mathbb Z}_2)$  explictly. Since there are only four 2-cochains $C_2 \times C_2 \to {\mathbb Z}_2$, you need to write them all down and then just apply the definition to decide which of them lie in $Z^2(..)$ and $B^2(..)$.

Comment: Sorry, I need remedial lessons in counting! There are of course 16 2-cochains.

Comment: @Derek Thanks, I will try your method! Could you answer the first question too?

Comment: @DerekHolt Also, does the identity $c(b_2,b_3) - c(b_1 b_2,b_3) + c(b_1,b_2 b_3) - c(b_1,b_2) = 0$ have to hold true for all possible combinations of $b_1, b_2, b_3$ in $C_2$ (for a given boolean function $c$)?

Comment: The definition of a $2$-cocycle is a $2$-cochain that satisfies that identity for  all $b_1,b_2,b_3 \in C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, so I found 4 co-cycles (corresponding to c0 = F0, c7 = F7, c8 =F8, c15 = F15 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/698086/568976)). But I'm not sure about how to find $B^2(B; A)$ now.  Out of $c0$, $c7$, $c8$, $c15$ how do I know which ones lie in $B^2(B;A)$?

Comment: I'm getting c0 ~ c7 and c0 ~ c15 for a certain single variable boolean function $d_1$ and c0 ~ c8 and c0 ~ c15 for another boolean function $d_2$.

Comment: You have been given the definition of $B^2(B,A)$. Work out all of its elements. Then you can check directly which 2-cocycles are 2-coboundaries.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm not sure what the elements of $B^2(B, A)$ are. There are 4 possible functions $d: C_2 \to C_2$. For one of them, say $d_1$, I get that $c_0(b_1, b_2) - c_8(b_1, b_2) = d_1(b_2) - d_1(b_1 b_2) + d_1(b_1)$ and $c_7(b_1, b_2) - c_{15}(b_1, b_2) = d_1(b_2) - d_1(b_1 b_2) + d_1(b_1)$. For another one of them, say $d_2$, I get that $c_0(b_1, b_2) - c_7(b_1, b_2) = d_2(b_2) - d_2(b_1 b_2) + d_2(b_1)$ and $c_8(b_1, b_2) - c_{15}(b_1, b_2) = d_2(b_2) - d_2(b_1 b_2) + d_2(b_1)$. The other two possible $d$ apparently do not produce any equivalence relation between $c_0, c_7, c_8, c_{15}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt "Then you can check directly which 2-cocycles are 2-coboundaries." ---- that apparently depends on the choice of the coboundary map $d$. And for two (out of four) possible coboundary maps, no two 2-cocycles are 2-coboundaries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106837/discussion-between-s-d-and-derek-holt).

Comment: Depending on the choice of the coboundary map $d$, $B^2(B, A)$ has either 2 elements or 1 element apparently (?).

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense. Every coboundary map $d$ defines an element of $B^2(B,A)$, but different coboundary maps could possibly define the same element.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you please write an answer showing how to compute the elements of $B^2(B; A)$? I'm getting really confused now. Or let's say $d_0$ is the 0 function (I.e., all outputs are 0). What's the corresponding element of $B^2(B;A)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt I found all possible images of  $d(b_2) - d(b_1 b_2) + d(b_1)$ (considering 4 different boolean function d's on a single variable) and it turns out to be exactly same as the four 2-cocycles I found earlier. $B^2(B;A) = Z^2(B;A)$ apparently...

Comment: Well you know that's wrong because you were told that the quotient group has order 2. I think $|B^2(B,A)|=2$ not 4.

Comment: @DerekHolt There are 4 possible d functions. 

$$d_0(0) = 0, d_0(1) = 0$$

$$d_1(0) = 0, d_1(1) = 1$$

$$d_2(0) = 1, d_2(1) = 0$$

$$d_3(0) = 1, d_3(1) = 1$$

You can check that each $d_i$ gives a distinct element in $B^2(B;A)$...

Comment: $$d_0(b_2) - d_0(b_1b_2) + d_0(b_1) = [0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]$$
$$d_1(b_2) - d_1(b_1b_2) + d_1(b_1) = [0 \ 1 \ 1 \ 1]$$
$$d_2(b_2) - d_2(b_1b_2) + d_2(b_1) = [1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]$$
$$d_3(b_2) - d_3(b_1b_2) + d_3(b_1) = [1 \ 1 \ 1 \ 1]$$

Comment: @DerekHolt Please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630532/trouble-evaluating-b2c-2-bbb-z-2-2-coboundaries

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. The second line, $d_1$, gives $[0 0 0 0]$ and the third line, $d_2$ gives $[1 1 1 1]$. It is correct for $d_0$ and $d_3$. (Note that $d_1$ is the identity map, which is a group homomrphism, so $d_1(b_2)-d_1(b_1b_2) + d_1(b_1)$ must be identically $0$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm not sure how $d_1$ gives $[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]$. Say, $b_1 = 0$ and $b_2 = 1$. Then $d_1(b_2) - d_1(b_1b_2) + d_1(b_1) = d_1(1) - d_1(0.1) + d_1(0) = 1 - 0 + 0 = 1$ and *not* $0$.

Comment: Oh, I understand my mistake. The group operation in $\Bbb Z_2$ is not multiplication but rather addition modulo 2. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekHolt Hi! Could you please have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633182/computing-h2c-2-bbb-z-2-using-linear-algebra-over-bbb-z-2?